# Android: Framebuffer missing attachment

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to create a render to texture class that has a framebuffer for position and a framebuffer for rotation. That part works great. But when I switch out and back to my app it crashes because checking the framebuffer status returns frameBuffer incomplete missing attachment.

```
public void setup(Context context) {
    final float eyeX = 0.0f;
    final float eyeY = 0.0f;
    final float eyeZ = 1.5f;

    final float lookX = 0.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = -5.0f;

    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

    int vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            ShaderHelper.readShader(context, R.raw.vertex_shader));     
    int fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            ShaderHelper.readShader(context, R.raw.fragment_shader));

    mProgramHandle = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, 
            new String[] {"a_Position", "a_TexCoord"});

    vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            ShaderHelper.readShader(context, R.raw.particle_vertex_shader));        
    fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            ShaderHelper.readShader(context, R.raw.particle_fragment_shader));

    mPartProgramHandle = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, 
            new String[] {"a_Position"});

    // create the ints for the framebuffer, depth render buffer and texture
    final int[] fb = new int[2];
    // generate
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(2, fb, 0);

    if (!setup) {
        posTex = ShaderHelper.genTexture(texW, texH, null);
        velTex = ShaderHelper.genTexture(texW, texH, null);
        rotTex = ShaderHelper.genTexture(texW, texH, null);
        rotVelTex = ShaderHelper.genTexture(texW, texH, null);
        atlasTex = ShaderHelper.loadTexture(context, R.drawable.ship_atlas);
    }
    posFb = fb[0];
    rotFb = fb[1];

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, posFb);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, posTex, 0);     
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, rotFb);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, rotTex, 0);


    final int buffers[] = new int[2];
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, spriteBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, spriteBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, renderQuad.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, renderQuad, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    mAtlasTexHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_TexAtlas");
    mPosTexHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_PosTexture");
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position"); 
    mTexCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoord");

    mXTexHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mPartProgramHandle, "u_Values");
    mDXTexHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mPartProgramHandle, "u_Transforms");
    mPassHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mPartProgramHandle, "u_Pass");
    mFBPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mPartProgramHandle, "a_Position"); 

    spriteBufferIdx = buffers[0];
    fbQuadBufferIdx = buffers[1];
    setup = true;

}
```

From what I have researched, textures do not need to be reloaded and only the framebuffers do. Which is good because then I would have to somehow put the pixels from the old texture into the new texture. But without remaking the textures it crashes with the framebuffer error. To make it clear, the code is ran everytime onSurfaceChanged is called.

How can I make it so I dont have to generate a new texture each time onSurfaceChanged is called without getting a FrameBuffer Incomplete Missing Attachment error?

Answer (score 0):

Since android recreates the context every time it is paused I needed to add this line

```
glSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
```